# How to create a set of css rules for safari

Tags: ios, css, iphone

### Background

I'm fixing a web app with an iframe but the iframe behaves differently on the iPhone than other devices so I need to give it its own set of styling.

### What I've tried

So I've tried a bunch of different styles and can get it to work mostly but not at the same time as the other mobile browsers. I need a way to point the styles to just the iphone safari browser.

I tried to write styles like this:

```
html[data-browser="iPhone"] .signup-iframe{
  /* the styles */
}
```

### Question

I put these changes on my server and then test on the iphone directly but it doesn't seem to get my new styles, why?

Comment: 1) Maybe it's better to go back to the beginning and consider what the differences in behaviour are. If there's a cause, maybe we can get rid of the cause rather than applying patches. 2) It looks like you're trying to give styles to iframe content from the container page, is that right? That won't work well.

Comment: yeah I thought so, but I've already tried stripping out the css. iphone and android treat iframe so differently I thought that adding styles to the individual devices would be the best solution. No I'm not trying to style the contense of the iframe, I'm styling the containing div it goes in (position, display height etc.).

Comment: Is your site live? I mean, can you provide a link?

Comment: its on a private server for work and I cant give it out, sorry. But what I don't understand is why the targeted css like above isnt working

Answer (score 1, accepted):

## ipods have different value in data-browser

It turns out that my code was working and that since I was using an old Ipod not an Iphone the value in data-browser was not matching up. It did, however work in Iphone when I checked on an Iphone 4 and Iphone 6.

Stupid mistake but hopefully this will help other people testing on an Ipod.